# Who waits in celery apply_async(countdown=10)

Tags: celery

I run celery worker with concurrency 20

```
"-c", "20", "-P", "eventlet", "-Ofair"
```

And generate packs of 20 task for this worker queue in another task

```
  async_call.apply_async(
       (call_id, engine),
       expires=60,
       countdown=60*random(),  # random delay, to prevent spikes
  )
```

In `flower` viewer i see that there are no more than 20 task.

Question is: who waiting the countdown?  is it inside the queue ? or it is inside worker process (some idle time of worker who take the task)?

If it is inside worker, then to use all CPU i need to increase concurrency according to fraction of countdown time (idle time) to work time.

Answer (score 0):

The wait is in a process / thread that each celery worker has that will poll the broker for new tasks if the worker is waiting for tasks.